# NASM Examples of Stack Addressing

Tags: assembly, stack, nasm, addressing

I am currently trying to learn about the types of addressing modes that NASM uses and I understand most of them such as direct, immediate, indirect, however; I am not sure what an example of Stack addressing would be.

I am thinking that a stack refers to a 2d array of some sort so a NASM code example could look something like:

```
x resd 5
mov dword [x], 1
```

I believe that the above code would be getting the base address of the array (the top of the stack) and insert the value 1 into the first 32 bits.

Is this true, and are there any other examples of stack addressing?

Thanks!

Comment: No, that's not stack addressing. It doesn't even exist, if you ask me ;) If you want you can define that as addressing in the stack segment, which is default for `esp` or `ebp`. As such, `mov eax, [esp+4]` could be stack addressing, but it's really just your everyday indirect addressing.

Comment: Go read [**The Art of Assembly Language Programming**](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/artofasm.html) -- Read it -- All of it. Even though most of it is for 8086 programming, all the fundamentals are 100% relevant to x86_64 assembly.  (chapter 4 covers basic addressing)